# Removing Ubuntu without loosing data

Tags: uninstall

Dear all
I want to remove ubuntu 14.04 and try Centos without using dual boot (to save space) this is the only OS I have in my labtop.
Do I will loose all data in my home directory and Downloads folder ?

Best Regards,

Comment: Yes,..please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)